# Different font sizes on website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

My website has a menu named Font Size. Basically its an option for user to change font size of website like:

```
smaller
small
medium
large
```

Default font size is "small". When user selects font size say "medium", then font size should remain medium throughout user's visit to all pages of that website(in one browser session). How to achieve this through JavaScript or jQuery or anything else.

I tried changing font size on selection but when I go to another page font size changes to default font size.

My website already using HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, Jquery. Its on Spring MVC/Java.

Comment: On modern browsers use local storage. For supporting all browsers (like old IE), consider to use cookie.

Comment: Use cookies to persist your font options in other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ideal world, you would have all over the elements on your page based on a percentage of the body font size, e.g.

```
body{ font-size: 12px; }
h1{ font-size: 120%; }
```

or

```
h1{ font-size: 1.5em; }
```

If you had this set up, then you can simply change the `font-size` of your body element, and this will then automagically update all the fonts on the page.

As Baadshah has suggested, you can use the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to persist your users selection across all pages.

I have put together a simple demo here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekLEp/)

You can change the body font-size based on the selection, set the cookie, and then check to see if this cookie exists, then set the font size.

```
if ( $.cookie('font-size') ){
    console.log($.cookie('font-size')); // take this out when not debugging
    $('body').css({ 'font-size': $.cookie('font-size')});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use cookies

```
 var cookieFont = $.cookie("fontSize");
  $("#target").css("font-size", curFont + 'px');
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ufetu5/2/edit)